# I want to start text from same position and also right aligned in a row

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, css-transitions

**Current Behavior**
[image]

I want to align the text in right of the page in a row,
Also the text should start from the same position based on the longest text in the same page.

current code

html:

```
<div class="row">
        <div>Titile</div>
    
        <span class="comment">
            long textelement
        </span>
    </div>

<div class="row">
    <div> Titile2</div>

    <span class="comment">
        small text
    </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row{
  width: 67%;
  display:flex;
}

.comment{
 margin-left: auto;
}
```

demo: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/4usdcLey/2/)

Expectation

[image]

Comment: Do you still need help on this?

Comment: @AlfredoLipari i found one alternative way to fix the issue, i will post the solution soon

Answer (score 0):

An easy workaround is to add a div container as a parent, so the child would align properly

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.row {
  width: 67%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div>Titile</div>

    <span class="comment">
      long textelement
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div> Titile2</div>

    <span class="comment">
      small text
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for  answer, but the content should be in the right corner of the row

Comment: please check the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lanhl.png

Answer (score 0):

You could add a new div around the content in the row that needs its content on the right. If that div has `width: fit-content` it will take the width of the biggest child(longest text) and makes it look like the result you wanted.

```css
.row{
  width: 67%;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.move-right{
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.row-items{
  width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div>
    Title
  </div>

  <span class="comment">
    long text element
  </span>
</div>

<div class="row move-right">
  <div class="row-items">
    <div>
      Titile2
    </div>

    <span class="comment">
      small text
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ramon de Vries, but the expectation is different, i.stack.imgur.com/Lanhl.png